# Average Number of items per date with google sheets and google data studio

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

Something broke and now I can't find the average number of new users per day.  I have a google sheet with new members (we are a community) and each member has a join date.  I want to find the average number of members who join per date and then I report on this in a google data studio report.  I'm drawing a blank here and it is driving me batty.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For example, a column with dates like this

It would be a column, with dates in it.. like

```
12/5/2020
12/6/2020
12/7/2020
12/7/2020
12/7/2020
12/7/2020
12/7/2020
12/7/2020
12/8/2020
12/8/2020
12/8/2020
12/8/2020
12/8/2020
12/8/2020
12/9/2020
```

I just want to count the dates and get an average.  heck, I had this working and something broke and it is broken.  weird.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(A:A; 
 "select count(A)
  where A is not null
  group by A
  label count(A)''"))
```

[image]